# CQ5 development using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aem

Am new to CQ5 and while going through the documents I found out that it comes with 2 development tools - CRXDE Lite, which is a browser based tool and the another one is CRXDE, which is based on eclipse, am pretty comfortable with both the tools. The issue is, in some of the CQ5 tutorials they suggest to use standalone eclipse for doing certain things, so am eager to know why is that required if we have CRXDE. Is there anything that we can't do using CRXDE?

Comment: What are those "some" tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRXDE and CRXDE Lite don't support a robust Software Development LifeCycle (SDLC) as they lack a lot of the tools of a full fledged IDE.  Some of the things which are a lot more difficult or not supported in these tools are:

1. Releases - You'll have to create releases manually using the package manager, which leads a lot more room for error, Maven + Eclipse allows for automatic releases
2. Source Control Management - They only support SVN and the integration is rather primitive compared to a full IDE
3. Continuous Integration - CRXDE and CRXDE Lite don't use build scripts which can be invoked by a CI server, you'll have to create them separately, in a real IDE, both the IDE and CI server can use the same
4. Java Development - Java development through CRXDE seems to take second fiddle to JSP development.  In my experience, this leads to sites build with business logic scattered throughout a labyrinth of messy JSP code.  A much better approach is to use an IDE which makes writing and maintaining Java Services easy and efficient.

To get you started, here's a webinar I did (sorry for the plug) about building CQ projects with Apache Maven:
http://www.6dlabs.com/blog/dklco/2012-06-05/webinar-cq5-development-setup-maven-build-and-deployment

and here's a blog post about releasing CQ projects with Maven:
[http://www.6dlabs.com/blog/dan-klco/2012-09-18/releasing-adobe-cq5-project-apache-maven](http://www.6dlabs.com/blog/dklco/2012-06-05/webinar-cq5-development-setup-maven-build-and-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that CRXDE is supported for the latest version of CQ (version 5.5).
CRXDE Lite is still supported though.

Generally CRXDE Lite is only really suitable for quite small pieces of development.  It has some SVN integration for code version control, but I think it's rather unreliable.  So for team projects, usually the combination is Eclipse as IDE, with SVN for version control and Maven to push workspace changes into the CRX repository.

Comment: I agree that CRXDE Lite only makes sense for small code bases and am too not sure if CRXDE is supported for CQ 5.5 or not. But my question is more about comparison of CRXDE with Eclipse. Can't I integrate SVN in CRXDE or for that matter use any of the standard eclipse features using it's plugins? What's the rational of not using CRXDE?

Comment: CRXDE IS SUPPORTED for development in CQ 5.5. Source: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/release_notes/overview.html. Current Release is 5.5 at the time of writing this comment.

Comment: @user1764832: CRXDE is integration compatible with SVN. You may find some SVN operations not working, which you might want to do them with CRXDE Lite. You may not be able to use plugins with CRXDE because it is an Eclipse RCP application.